# PageViewController dots disappear when returning to the view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have an app that presents a PageViewController tutorial scene. In my settings page I have a button that returns to the PageViewController, labeled IntroViewController.

When the tutorial first appears, it works fine. But when I go back, the dots at the base of the PageViewController disappear. Any idea why this happens?

Here is the IntroViewController.m

```
#import "IntroViewController.h"

@interface IntroViewController ()

@end

@implementation IntroViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Create the data model
_pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Another one!"];
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
_pageImages = @[@"IntroExpand.png", @"IntroSlow.png", @"IntroImport.png", @"IntroRename.png"];
}
else {
     _pageImages = @[@"IntroExpand.png", @"IntroSlow.png", @"IntroImport.png", @"IntroRename.png"];
}
// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 5);

[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.ready];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



- (IBAction)ready:(id)sender { //this is the action that the user does to dismiss the tutorial and go to the first scene


UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
    return nil;
}
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
    return nil;
}

// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.imageFiles = self.pageImages[index];
pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

return pageContentViewController;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return 0;
}
@end
```

Here is the IntroViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface IntroViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

- (IBAction)ready:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ready;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageTitles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages;

@end
```

And here is the button/action that takes the user from the settings page to the tutorial. I've tried different segues, modal, push, etc., and they all have the same problem of not displaying the dots when the user returns to the tutorial

```
- (IBAction)tutorialReplay:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IntroViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Let me know if I need to add more code to help. Thanks all.

Comment: If you're trying to go back to the same IntroViewController that you started with, the code you have doesn't do that. It creates a new instance of it. You need to get a reference to the one you already have. How to do that depends on your controller hierarchy. How are IntroViewController and the settings controller related (does one create the other, what kind of transition from one to the other are you using, etc.)?

Comment: Yeah, @rdelmar obviously creating 2 references is sloppy, but that doesn't explain why the OP's viewDidLoad doesn't properly instantiate the view the second time around...unless...one sec...

Comment: OP, I think the question might lie in `PageContentViewController`. How are you structuring the view? Is there a scrollview in combo with a page view controller? Or are you structuring it in some other way? And how many views are supposed to be attached to the intro view's page view controller?

Comment: I found the problem. Had to do with the dot's default color being white. I found in my AppDelegate (where I establish defaults so that the tutorial isn't seen a second time) that I had changed the pagecontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor to black, but it wasn't done when the user goes back to the PageContentViewController. Thanks for tips all.